# Default size of IdentityHashMap is incorrect ? Why

Tags: java, hashmap

In  default constructor of `IdentityHashMap` class, a private `init()` method is called which makes default size as `64`.

Please find the code below :

```
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 32;

 public IdentityHashMap() {
        init(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }

private void init(int initCapacity) {
       table = new Object[2 * initCapacity];
}
```

**But in documentation [JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html#IdentityHashMap--), it is written that default size is 21 based on 32 default capacity and load factor.**

Please help me understand this behavior. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You're confusing "capacity" and "expected maximum  size". The documentation says: "This class has one tuning parameter (which affects performance but not semantics): expected maximum size. This parameter is the maximum number of key-value mappings that the map is expected to hold. Internally, this parameter is used to determine the number of buckets initially comprising the hash table. The precise relationship between the expected maximum size and the number of buckets is unspecified. ".

Comment: @JBNizet - If you could please paste your comment as answer , so that I can accept that

Answer (score 4):

If you look at implementation of `IdentityHashMap`, then you see that it stores key-value mappings in the array field `table`. Each mapping consumes 2 elements from that array, one for the key and one for the value. So the array of length 64 can accommodate maximum 32 mappings. But as `IdentityHashMap` has default load factor of `2/3` you get 21 mappings.